# How can I get Get All Filenames in a Folder using Visual C++?

Tags: c++, directory

I tried this code but I am not getting any ouput. It does not throw error also.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;
   memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
   HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("c:\\*.txt", &search_data);
while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
  printf("Found file: %s\r\n", search_data.cFileName);

  if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
    break;
 }

 return 0;
}`
```

Comment: If you have Boost, you can do this with iterators in a way that will work not just on Windows. Anyway, you say it gives no errors, but do no error checking. If the first call returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, you'll have no idea why.

Comment: Do you actually have any .txt files in the root of your C: drive?

Comment: it means your handle is invalid, can you get the last error and see?

Answer (score 0):

```
//using boost file system.    
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::filesystem;

    path myPath(L"D:\\Article");
    for (auto beg = directory_iterator(myPath); beg != directory_iterator();   ++beg) {
    std::cout << *beg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @lincoln, you should describe what modification you make to the code and why. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any output because `FindFirstFile()` is failing and you are ignoring the error.  ALWAYS check API error codes.

Try this instead.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;
     DWORD err;

     memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

     HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("c:\\*.txt", &search_data);
     if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {
         err = GetLastError();
         if (err == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
             printf("No files were found\r\n");
         else
             printf("Unable to search for files. Error: %u\r\n", err);
     }
     else
     {
         do
         {
             if ((search_data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
                 printf("Found file: %s\r\n", search_data.cFileName);
         }
         while (FindNextFile(handle, &search_data));

         err = GetLastError();
         if (err == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
             printf("Done\r\n");
         else
             printf("Unable to search for files. Error: %u\r\n", err);

         FindClose(handle);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input.It throws error at the first "Unable to search for files".. nyway to overcome this?

Comment: It gives you an error code.  What is the actual value that is being reported? Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx)?: "If the function fails or fails to locate files from the search string in the lpFileName parameter, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and the contents of lpFindFileData are indeterminate. To get extended error information, call the GetLastError function. If the function fails because no matching files can be found, the GetLastError function returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND."